# Communicating events between two sibling components in angular

Tags: angular

In my parent html template, I have:

```
<floor (floorCodeChanged)="setSelectedFloorCode($event)"></floor>
 <room></room>
```

In my parent.ts file, I have a function that sets the floorCode:

```
setSelectedFloorCode(floorCode: string) {
    this.floor = floorCode;
 }
```

My floor html template is:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select (selectionChange)="emitChangedFloorCode($event)">
        <mat-option> 1 </mat-option>
        <mat-option> 2 </mat-option>
        ...
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

In my floor.ts file, I have:

```
@Output() floorCodeChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

...

```
emitChangedFloorCode($event: MatSelectChange) {
    this.floorCodeChanged.emit($event.value);
}
```

As soon as the floorCodeChanged has emitted the event, I want my room component to call a function inside room.ts file to do something with the change like:

```
<floor (floorCodeChanged)="setSelectedFloorCode($event)"></floor>
<room (onFloorCodeChange)="doSomething($event)></room>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a shared service containing a **Subject**.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  event$ = new Subject<string>();
}
```

After you have *provided* the service in the components parent module, you can inject the shared service with

```js
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}
```

and dispatch events between components by

```js
emitChangedFloorCode($event: MatSelectChange) {
  this.sharedService.event$.next($event.value);
}
```

and you can listen to these events by subscribing to the subject

```js
this.sharedService.event$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```